# How to create Wordpress Hook-like in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I'm new to NextJS. I've been looking around to the right tutorial for this but I still don't have luck of finding one.

How to do Wordpress Hook-like in NextJS? It's like, when you want to insert a different content on each page but it puts on a specific place.

This is what I am actually expecting to do:

This is what's inside my default-layout.js

```
export default function DefaultLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <main className="main-content" role="main">
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />
      <Bottom />
    </>
  )
  
}
```

and I have this on each of my page (eg. about.js)

```
const About = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <PageContent>
        <h1>props.title</h1>
        <p>props.content</p>
      </PageContent>
      <Bottom>
        <Modal>I'm going to put modal here</Modal>
      </Bottom>
    </>
  )
  
}
export default About
```

Where `<Bottom>`'s content is different from services.js page *(services.js also have `<Bottom>` component)*. And it is all always placed after `<Footer />`.

The reason why I'd like it to be this way is because each page has different modal contents.

Is my logic right? The problem is that I cannot find a NextJS tutorial for this. Or maybe I just don't know the right keyword to use for this? Is it called "Component Hook" or "Component Inject"?

Can somebody help me how to achieve this or at least share some tutorial link on how it's done?

```
Update:
```

Updating this question to fully understand the situation.

Given that I have this in my about.js page:

```
const About = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <PageContent>
        <h1>props.title</h1>
        <p>props.content</p>
      </PageContent>
      <Bottom>
        <Modal>I'm going to put modal here</Modal>
      </Bottom>
    </>
  )
}
```

Even if I change the position of `<Bottom></Bottom>` component:

```
const About = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Bottom>
        <Modal>I'm going to put modal here</Modal>
      </Bottom>
      <PageContent>
        <h1>props.title</h1>
        <p>props.content</p>
      </PageContent>
    </>
  )
}
```

The content I put in the `<Bottom></Bottom>` within the about.js page should still show at the bottom of the page after `<Footer />` component in the default-layout.js:

```
export default function DefaultLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navigation />
      <main className="main-content" role="main">
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />
      <Bottom />
    </>
  )
  
}
```

NextJS' have the same component like this. It is when using the `<head></head>` component.

```
const About = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Overriding the "About Us" title here</title>
      </Head>
      <Bottom>
        <Modal>I'm going to put modal here</Modal>
      </Bottom>
      <PageContent>
        <h1>props.title</h1>
        <p>props.content</p>
      </PageContent>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now, I wonder how to do this in footer or my `<Bottom />` so that whenever I create modal on each page, it will always stay after `<Footer />`?

Comment: Would the `bottom` only contain a modal with different text? Or would it have different components in it?

Comment: @rguarascia.ts Thank you for noticing! It can have different components or even different HTML structure inside of it.